# Tomcat refuses to deploy CSS files

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Okay I am using Tomcat to deploy my Web-App. The files in /WebContent Directory are-:

```
chat.html
chat.js
chat.css
```

and a few .jpg files.

Now when I deploy the application through eclipse all the files are deployed except

```
chat.css
```

It is not present in the `wtwebapps` directory of Tomcat. Why is that ?

Also I can't serve any new files. For example if I put a file called a.js in my `WebContent` folder it is also not deployed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you edit the files that *are* being deployed, do they change in the `wtwebapps` directory?

Comment: @dcsohl No. They don't.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it. Whenever you put in a new file(s) in the web-content directory. Make sure to go to eclipse and right click on your project and select `Refresh`. Then you can deploy the project in Tomcat.